# How to read an element from a Scala HList?

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0, hlist

There is very few readable documentation about HLists, and the answers I can find on SO come from outer space for a humble Scala beginner.

I encountered HLists because Slick can auto-generate some to represent database rows. They are `slick.collection.heterogeneous.HList` (not shapeless').
Example:

```
type MyRow = HCons[Int,HCons[String,HCons[Option[String],HCons[Int,HCons[String,HCons[Int,HCons[Int,HCons[Option[Int],HCons[Option[Float],HCons[Option[Float],HCons[Option[String],HCons[Option[String],HCons[Boolean,HCons[Option[String],HCons[Option[String],HCons[Option[String],HCons[Option[String],HCons[Option[String],HCons[Option[Int],HCons[Option[Float],HCons[Option[Float],HCons[Option[Float],HCons[Option[String],HCons[Option[String],HNil]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
def MyRow(a, b, c, ...): MyRow = a :: b :: c :: ... :: HNil
```

Now given one of these rows, I'd need to read one element, typed if possible. I just can't do that. I tried

```
row(4)  // error
row._4  // error
row.toList  // elements are inferred as Any
row match { case a :: b :: c :: x :: rest => x }  // "Pattern type is incompatible. Expected MyRow."
row match { case MyRow(_,_,_,_,_,x,...) => x }  // is not a case class like other rows
row match { HCons[Int,HCons[String,HCons[Option[String],HCons[Int,HCons[String, x]]]]] => x.head }  // error
row.tail.tail.tail.tail.head  // well, is that really the way??
```

Could somebody please explain how I can extract a specific value from that dinosaur?

Comment: that...... `dinosaur`.... It seems you are quite terrified of `HList`'s.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh no need to emit opinions that reflect on the character of a person you don't know. Could I suggest you remove that comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect your `row(0)` lookup to work based on the [HList API doc for `apply`](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/api/index.html#slick.collection.heterogeneous.HList). Here's an example I tried with Slick 3.1.1:

```
scala> import slick.collection.heterogeneous._
import slick.collection.heterogeneous._

scala> import slick.collection.heterogeneous.syntax._
import slick.collection.heterogeneous.syntax._

scala> type MyRow = Int :: String :: HNil
defined type alias MyRow

scala> val row: MyRow = 1 :: "a" :: HNil
row: MyRow = 1 :: a :: HNil

scala> row(0) + 99
res1: Int = 100

scala> val a: String = row(1)
a: String = a
```

Comment: I tried with this new import, and for me `row(0)` is of type `Any`, even though `row.head` is of type `Int`.

Comment: Oh wait, IntellIJ underlines it as an error ("Any does not conform to expected type Int"), but it actually does compile. I don't understand how this is possible though.

Comment: Two things:  the result from `row(0)` is a type alias that eventually is `Int`, and it could be that IntelliJ is confused by that. Also: there's a macro involved in figuring that out, which could be a source of confusion in IntelliJ - I don't know :-(  Also, if you're using a run-time value (like `val n=0; row(n)` as opposed to a literal like `row(0)`) I think you will end up with `Any`.

Comment: I see. Just one more thing: do you have any idea why this other solution `val a: String = row.drop(1).head` does not work? ("HList#Head does not conform to expected type String" - and this time it does not compile).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I suggest opening a new SO question on that,

Answer (score 0):

Just one thing... if it is not too important than just stick to `HList` as the `type`. Do not `alias` it to `MyRow` unless necessary.

So.. you had

```
val row = a :: b :: c :: ... :: HNil
```

How about this ?

```
val yourX = row match { case a :: b :: c :: x ::: rest => x }
```

notice that `:::` instead of `::` at the end.

Or... how about this,

```
val yourX = row.tail.tail.tail.head

// this may change a little if you had,
def MyRow(a, b, c, ...): MyRow = a :: b :: c :: ... :: HNil

val row = MyRow(a, b, c, ...)

val yourX = row.asInstanceOf[HList].tail.tail.tail.head
```

Comment: Sbt says "Cannot resolve symbol ':::' ". The second solution is what I use at the moment, just imagine I want elements 12, 14, 15, 17, 26 and 27... But if there is no other solution, I'll keep that.

Comment: This ":::" is in the scaladocs indeed but I can't make it work in pattern matching. There should be a way to use `.drop` instead of `.tail.tail.tail...` but I couldn't made it work either. Thanks for answering though.